# Bit tricky plot on GRE

Tags: contest-math, gre-exam, ratio

> In a city ***90%*** of the population own a car, ***15%***  own a motor cycle, and everybody owns one or the other or both. Find the percentage of  motorcycle owners to car owners.

In order to solve it i have first found out that  ***5%*** are the guys `who owns owns one or the other or both`. Now I require, `Find the percentage of  motorcycle owners to car owners.`

I have added for car-ians : $90\,\% + 5\,\%=95\,\%$.

And motorcycl-ians: $15\,\% +5\,\%=20\,\%$.

Found out the ratio as $4:19$ but found it incorrect.
why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good try, but you zigged when you should have zagged.

$90\%$ own a car, but some might also own a motorcycle.  $15\%$ own a motorcycle, but some might also own a car.

It is correct that $5\%$ own both.  But that means that $85\%$ own *only* a car, and $10\%$ own *only* a motorcycle.  Those add up to $100\%$, as they should.

If you're looking for the ratio of motorcycle-only owners to car-only owners, it's $10/85 = 2/17.$

If you're looking for the ratio of motorcycle owners to car owners (regardless of whether or not they own both) it's $15/90 = 1/6$.